# "Visualizing [and Understanding] Recurrent Networks" using LSTM's cell state at each timestep

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, lstm

I am currently trying to programmatically visualize the way deep learning approaches learn/train on my problems and e.g. stumbled upon the paper "Visualizing and Understanding Recurrent Networks" by Andrej Karpathy, Justin Johnson, and Li Fei-Fei (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02078).

In figure 2 they calculate the tanh of the memory/cell states (*c*) of their LSTMs at each timestep during prediction.
I now want to do the same with my LSTMs in Keras (or PyTorch, but I'm quite new to their API). The API allows me to get the hidden states (*h*) for each timestep - using the parameter `return_sequences=True`, but only the last cell state - using the parameter `return_state=True`.

With my understanding of the Keras API I currently create two models:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))

embd = Embedding(input_dim=MAX_FEATURES, output_dim=128, input_length=MAX_LEN)(inputs)
lstm = LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True)(embd)

# 'ignore' return_sequences=True in training model
flt = Flatten()(lstm)

drp = Dropout(0.5)(flt)
dns = Dense(N_CLASSES)(drp)
activ = Activation('softmax')(dns)

training_model = Model([inputs], [activ])
state_model = Model([inputs], [activ, lstm])

training_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
training_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions, hidden_states = state_model.predict(X_test)
```

How do I do the same for the cell state at each timestep (character in my case) - preferably without having to override/reimplement 'major' parts of Keras'/PyTorch's source code?
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971673/7248668), but haven't gotten it to work and as I don't have enough reputation I can't add any questions in the comments (I saw the other answer but I want to prevent a 'complete' reimplementation of Keras' LSTMCell).

**EDIT #1**: As I'm quite new to PyTorch's API - how would I go about there?